# Relation between Hebrew 'סמפוניה' and English 'Symphony'

Tags: english, cross-linguistic, hebrew, ancient

In the [Mishna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishna), it mentions a musical instrument called a 'סמפוניה', transliterated 'Simp-O-nya'.

This sounds rather like the [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) word [symphony](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/symphony?s=t), which is a musical composition.

What is the relation between the two words?

Comment: Symfonia in Greek means "voice (sound) together", in modern transscribation meaning "coordinated sound(s)".
In modern Greek "symfonia" may even mean an agreement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They both come from Greek συμφωνία.This was used in ancient and mediaeval times as a name for various musical instruments, including a type of drum.

Comment: Yes, or more literally: "having a sound together".

Comment: Also in modern times in Spanish there are at least two instruments with names derived from this: *zampoña* ([siku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siku_(instrument))), an Andean panpipe; and *zanfona*, a [hurdy-gurdy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurdy-gurdy).